# Unable to access ffdf file from .RData

Tags: r, ff

I loaded big data files (https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction) using the `read.csv.ff` command from `ff` package using the following command:

```
 train = read.csv.ffdf(file="path to my big data files/train.csv",VERBOSE=TRUE)
```

then save it using the usual save workspace from `RStudio`. It created two files:

an `.RData` file and `.ffData` one which is a compressed file.

Everything worked fine but each time I restart my computer or close `RStudio` and open `RStudio` again, I'm unable to access `ffdf` objects from my workspace giving the error:

```
 >train[1,]

    file.access(filename, 0) == 0 is not TRUE
```

Or I can see the `ffobject` in the workspace I loaded.

What is this problem? how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
HR

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines.  You have not provided your code, so we have no idea what `train` is or how you built it.  I'm making an unjustified guess that your `train` is an `ff` object, in which case rather obviously you either deleted the `.ffData` file it belongs to, changed its permissions, or did some other bad thing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'ffsave', not 'save', and then 'ffload' when you want to read it back in again. So, something like:

```
ffsave(train,file = 'mynamedtrainfile)
```